# submitting form programmatically

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

Im trying to submit a specific form programatically, but I allways get the initial page back.
I must be doing something wrong or missing something here.
Im sending the session cookie and some POST data like viewState (that I parse from the initial request), and SessionID (this is the value i change in the form toget data from other years). But in the second request I allways get data for Session 899, instead of the one i request: 875.

Here is the code used:, any help is greatly apreciated

retrieveEdmIndexForSession(875);

```
 protected string retrieveEdmIndexForSession(int sessionId) {

    CookieContainer cookies;
    HttpWebRequest oRequest;
    HttpWebResponse oResponse;
    Stream sw;
    StreamReader sr;
    string pageData;
string PathRemote = @"http://edmi.parliament.uk/EDMi/EDMList.aspx";


    /*
     * download the index page so we can get Cookies and ViewState from it.
     */
    oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PathRemote);
    oRequest.Method = "GET";
    oRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    oRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    oRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    oRequest.Referer = "http://edmi.parliament.uk/EDMi/EDMList.aspx";


    oResponse =(HttpWebResponse) oRequest.GetResponse();
    sr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream());

    pageData = sr.ReadToEnd();

    /*
     * extract view state from pageData.
     */
    string viewState = this.ExtractViewState(pageData);


    /*
    * lets submit the form with the parameters we want
    */
    oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PathRemote);
    oRequest.Method = "POST";
    oRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    oRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    oRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    oRequest.CookieContainer.Add(oResponse.Cookies);
    oRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    oRequest.Referer = "http://edmi.parliament.uk/EDMi/EDMList.aspx";

    string postdata = "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState + "&_MenuCtrl%3AddlSession=" + sessionId + "&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.x=57&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.y=14&ddlStatus=1&ddlSortedBy=1";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
    oRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    /*
     * Send post data into request stream first
     */
    sw = oRequest.GetRequestStream();
    sw.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();

    /*
     * Connect, send and get response
     */
    oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse();
    sr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream());

    //OnLogUpdated(1, "\r\nStatus Code: " + oResponse.StatusCode);
    //OnLogUpdated(1, "\r\nServer: " + oResponse.Server);

    pageData = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string result = getSessionId(pageData);
    //OnLogUpdated(1, "\r\nRestuls: [" + result + "]");
    //OnLogUpdated(1, "\r\nPage: [" + pageData + "]");


    return pageData;


}



private string ExtractViewState(string str)
{
    string viewState = "";
    string pattern = "(?<=__VIEWSTATE\" value=\")(?<val>.*?)(?=\")";

    Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        viewState = match.Groups["val"].Value;
        viewState = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(viewState);

    }

    return viewState;
}

protected string getSessionId(string str)
{
    string sessionId = string.Empty;

    str = str.Trim();

    string pattern = @"&SESSION=([^']+)'";

    Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        sessionId = match.Groups[1].ToString(); ;

    }

    return sessionId;
}
```

This is the RAW Request being sent by the .NET script.

> POST /EDMi/EDMList.aspx HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Referer:
>   http://edmi.parliament.uk/EDMi/EDMList.aspx
>   User-Agent: .NET Framework Client
>   Host: edmi.parliament.uk Cookie:
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=k55fqarvx2oszp2wxhtrol45
>   Content-Length: 2431 Expect:
>   100-continue
>
> __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=dDwxMDgyNzIxNDQ2O3Q8O2w8aTwzPjs%2bO2w8dDw7bDxpPDE%2bO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDExPjs%2bO2w8dDw7bDxpPDEzPjtpPDE3Pjs%2bO2w8dDx0PHA8cDxsPERhdGFWYWx1ZUZpZWxkO0RhdGFUZXh0RmllbGQ7PjtsPFNFU1NJT05JRDtJVEVNX1ZBTFVFOz4%2bOz47dDxpPDIwPjtAPDA4LTA5OzA3LTA4OzA2LTA3OzA1LTA2OzA0LTA1OzAzLTA0OzAyLTAzOzAxLTAyOzAwLTAxOzk5LTAwOzk4LTk5Ozk3LTk4Ozk2LTk3Ozk1LTk2Ozk0LTk1OzkzLTk0OzkyLTkzOzkxLTkyOzkwLTkxOzg5LTkwOz47QDw4OTk7ODkxOzg4NTs4NzU7ODczOzY4Mjs2ODE7NjgwOzY3OTs3MDM7NzAyOzcwMTs3MDA7Njk5OzY5ODs2OTc7Njk2OzY5NTs2OTQ7NjkzOz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2bO2w8TGlzdCBPZiBFYXJseSBEYXkgTW90aW9uczs%2bPjs7Pjs%2bPjt0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjs%2bO2w8dDx0PDs7bDxpPDA%2bOz4%2bOzs%2bO3Q8dDw7O2w8aTwwPjs%2bPjs7Pjs%2bPjt0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjs%2bO2w8dDw7bDxpPDE%2bO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDc%2bOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztFbmFibGVkO18hU0I7PjtsPDA7UGFnZUZpcnN0RGlzYWJsZWQ7bzxmPjtpPDI%2bOz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxDb21tYW5kQXJndW1lbnQ7Q3NzQ2xhc3M7RW5hYmxlZDtfIVNCOz47bDwtMTtQYWdlUHJldkRpc2FibGVkO288Zj47aTwyPjs%2bPjs%2bOzs%2bO3Q8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO18hU0I7PjtsPDE7UGFnZU5leHRFbmFibGVkO2k8Mj47Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztfIVNCOz47bDw0MjtQYWdlTGFzdEVuYWJsZWQ7aTwyPjs%2bPjs%2bOzs%2bOz4%2bO3Q8O2w8aTwxPjtpPDM%2bO2k8NT47aTw3Pjs%2bO2w8dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwyMTA5Oz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxFRE1zIGFuZCBBbWVuZG1lbnRzOz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwxOz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1MDs%2bPjs%2bOzs%2bOz4%2bOz4%2bO3Q8O2w8aTwxPjtpPDM%2bOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjtpPDU%2bO2k8Nz47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO0VuYWJsZWQ7XyFTQjs%2bO2w8MDtQYWdlRmlyc3REaXNhYmxlZDtvPGY%2bO2k8Mj47Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztFbmFibGVkO18hU0I7PjtsPC0xO1BhZ2VQcmV2RGlzYWJsZWQ7bzxmPjtpPDI%2bOz4%2bOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxDb21tYW5kQXJndW1lbnQ7Q3NzQ2xhc3M7XyFTQjs%2bO2w8MTtQYWdlTmV4dEVuYWJsZWQ7aTwyPjs%2bPjs%2bOzs%2bO3Q8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO18hU0I7PjtsPDQyO1BhZ2VMYXN0RW5hYmxlZDtpPDI%2bOz4%2bOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxWaXNpYmxlOz47bDxvPGY%2bOz4%2bOz47bDxpPDE%2bO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDc%2bOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDIxMDk7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEVETXMgYW5kIEFtZW5kbWVudHM7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDUwOz4%2bOz47Oz47Pj47Pj47Pj47Pj47bDxfTWVudUN0cmw6X0dvVG87Pj5NHcFbPBNzNuwxs7sYLdUE2omkjw%3d%3d&_MenuCtrl%3AddlSession=875&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.x=57&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.y=14&ddlStatus=1&ddlSortedBy=1

This is the RAW request sent by IE:

> POST /EDMi/EDMList.aspx HTTP/1.1
>   Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg,
>   image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg,
>   application/x-shockwave-flash,
>   application/xaml+xml,
>   application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument,
>   application/x-ms-xbap,
>   application/x-ms-application,
>   application/vnd.ms-excel,
>   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
>   application/msword, */* Referer:
>   http://edmi.parliament.uk/EDMi/EDMList.aspx
>   Accept-Language: en-gb User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
>   Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR
>   1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;
>   OfficeLivePatch.0.0; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Host:
>   edmi.parliament.uk Content-Length:
>   2431 Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma:
>   no-cache Cookie:
>   WT_FPC=id=83.217.99.254-2364242496.30021299:lv=1249572414567:ss=1249572414567;
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=vwxgo4rlex1j5m55l0bivrqo
>
> __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=dDwxMDgyNzIxNDQ2O3Q8O2w8aTwzPjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDE%2BO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDExPjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDEzPjtpPDE3Pjs%2BO2w8dDx0PHA8cDxsPERhdGFWYWx1ZUZpZWxkO0RhdGFUZXh0RmllbGQ7PjtsPFNFU1NJT05JRDtJVEVNX1ZBTFVFOz4%2BOz47dDxpPDIwPjtAPDA4LTA5OzA3LTA4OzA2LTA3OzA1LTA2OzA0LTA1OzAzLTA0OzAyLTAzOzAxLTAyOzAwLTAxOzk5LTAwOzk4LTk5Ozk3LTk4Ozk2LTk3Ozk1LTk2Ozk0LTk1OzkzLTk0OzkyLTkzOzkxLTkyOzkwLTkxOzg5LTkwOz47QDw4OTk7ODkxOzg4NTs4NzU7ODczOzY4Mjs2ODE7NjgwOzY3OTs3MDM7NzAyOzcwMTs3MDA7Njk5OzY5ODs2OTc7Njk2OzY5NTs2OTQ7NjkzOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8TGlzdCBPZiBFYXJseSBEYXkgTW90aW9uczs%2BPjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjs%2BO2w8dDx0PDs7bDxpPDA%2BOz4%2BOzs%2BO3Q8dDw7O2w8aTwwPjs%2BPjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDE%2BO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDc%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztFbmFibGVkO18hU0I7PjtsPDA7UGFnZUZpcnN0RGlzYWJsZWQ7bzxmPjtpPDI%2BOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxDb21tYW5kQXJndW1lbnQ7Q3NzQ2xhc3M7RW5hYmxlZDtfIVNCOz47bDwtMTtQYWdlUHJldkRpc2FibGVkO288Zj47aTwyPjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO18hU0I7PjtsPDE7UGFnZU5leHRFbmFibGVkO2k8Mj47Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztfIVNCOz47bDw0MjtQYWdlTGFzdEVuYWJsZWQ7aTwyPjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwxPjtpPDM%2BO2k8NT47aTw3Pjs%2BO2w8dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwyMTA5Oz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxFRE1zIGFuZCBBbWVuZG1lbnRzOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwxOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1MDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwxPjtpPDM%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MT47aTwzPjtpPDU%2BO2k8Nz47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO0VuYWJsZWQ7XyFTQjs%2BO2w8MDtQYWdlRmlyc3REaXNhYmxlZDtvPGY%2BO2k8Mj47Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPENvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudDtDc3NDbGFzcztFbmFibGVkO18hU0I7PjtsPC0xO1BhZ2VQcmV2RGlzYWJsZWQ7bzxmPjtpPDI%2BOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxDb21tYW5kQXJndW1lbnQ7Q3NzQ2xhc3M7XyFTQjs%2BO2w8MTtQYWdlTmV4dEVuYWJsZWQ7aTwyPjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8Q29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50O0Nzc0NsYXNzO18hU0I7PjtsPDQyO1BhZ2VMYXN0RW5hYmxlZDtpPDI%2BOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxWaXNpYmxlOz47bDxvPGY%2BOz4%2BOz47bDxpPDE%2BO2k8Mz47aTw1PjtpPDc%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDIxMDk7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEVETXMgYW5kIEFtZW5kbWVudHM7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDUwOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47Pj47Pj47Pj47bDxfTWVudUN0cmw6X0dvVG87Pj5NHcFbPBNzNuwxs7sYLdUE2omkjw%3D%3D&_MenuCtrl%3AddlSession=885&ddlStatus=0&ddlSortedBy=1&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.x=37&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.y=12

The IE Header seems to have an extra cookie(WT_FPC=id=83.217.99.254-2364242496.30021299:lv=1249572414567:ss=1249572414567;) witch appers to track visitors using cookies via the WebTrends Cookie Plug-In. Both POST Requests Return HTTP Status Code 302 and redirect to a GET request that returns status 200.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried hooking up Fiddler and diffing a genuine request compared to your programmatically crafted one? There must be a difference somewhere.

Comment: I have been trying to figre this out with Fiddler. I will update the post with the RAW data of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cracked it. It seems that the .NET server does not like me changing the Status and the Session at the same time.
It works if i change the "ddlStatus" from:

> string postdata =
>   "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE="
>   + viewState + "&_MenuCtrl%3AddlSession=" + sessionId
>   + "&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.x=57&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.y=14&ddlStatus=1&ddlSortedBy=1";

to this:

> string postdata =
>   "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE="
>   + viewState + "&_MenuCtrl%3AddlSession=" + sessionId
>   + "&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.x=57&_MenuCtrl%3A_GoTo.y=14&ddlStatus=0&ddlSortedBy=1";

I will have to change the ddlStatus in a second POST request, and so on for each change in the form. .NET seems to be very well educated, It can only take one sweet at a time.

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 3):

**You are creating a new CookieContainer each time.** Try using the CookieContainer of the index page request as the container for the form submit, it should contain the extra cookie. Alternatively, something other than the form could be passing the extra cookie. Check when the page loads using IEinspector's [HttpAnalyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/) or Firefox's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to make sure other form elements like images aren't passing the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not related to your problem, but sometimes when you scrape a site the remote server recognize that the one who's browsing is a script and block some operations. I usually workaround this via setting UserAgent property to the request. It's a poor security measure, but often used in my experience.

[Here you can find some sample user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/).

Comment: I have tried with different UserAgents with no success. This appears not to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that struck me as odd in that request is the `Expect` header. [Apparently it's caused problems for people in the past](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx). To stop that you can use the following line:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

If that is the problem it's probably worth setting that property back to whatever it was before, since it's a global variable and may well affect other parts of your code.

Comment: Pike65: I was just looking into this. I have set  oRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false; This removes the line from the header, but still my issue remains :(